# SQL Server 2012 -- xp_fileexist returns 0 when checking for file on local machine

Tags: sql-server

The SQL server exists on the same machine I am physically logged into, and xp_fileexist is failing to recognize any files on the D drive, which is **not** a network drive.  I already configured xp_cmdshell and restarted the SQL server instance.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have permissions on D:\? Are you looking in the root or a subfolder? (There are some restrictions in the root of fixed drives.)

Comment: I'm looking in a subfolder.  I don't see an option to ad the SQL Server Service account when I check security.

Comment: Well, what account is the SQL Server service running under?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but `xp_fileexist` is an undocumented stored procedure so even if it's fairly well known there's no guarantee that it will do what you want; writing your own CLR procedure would be safer. And I don't know why you want to interact with the file system from within SQL Server, but using an external script is often easier.

Comment: It is logged on as NT Service\MSSQLSERVER

Comment: I fixed it by having it log on as Local System instead! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yup, we had the same problem.  On SQL Server 2008, our legacy `xp_fileexist` code worked fine, but on SQL Server 2012... *nope*.

It would work if we ran the `xp_fileexist` command as ourselves (with Admin rights) but not when we ran it as a SQL Server user, who didn't exist as an Active Directory user.  Even if we changed the security on that folder to give `Everyone` full permissions, the `xp_fileexist` would fail, always returning a 0, as if a file within that folder didn't exist.

However, what *did* work was to use `dir` from within a Stored Procedure, and test if the file existed that way.  (Yeah, I know... I'm rolling my eyes myself... this is dodgy..)

Here's the Stored Procedure I wrote, based on [suggestions on this site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e98561b4-0d5c-45e5-989c-a042f7a3b298/check-file-exists-or-not-using-sql-server-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices) :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DoesFileExist]
( 
    @directoryName NVARCHAR(500),
    @filename NVARCHAR(500)
)
AS
BEGIN
    --  Does a file exist in a particular folder ?
    --  
    --      EXEC [dbo].[DoesFileExist] 'D:\MyFiles', 'SomeExcelFile.xls'
    --
    DECLARE @bFileExists INT

    DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(300);
    SELECT @cmd = 'dir ' + @directoryName + '\' + @filename;

    DECLARE @dir TABLE ([output] varchar( 2000 ))

    INSERT INTO @dir
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd;

    --  Uncomment the following line, if you want to see what 
    --  a "dir" looks like from SQL Server !!    
    --  SELECT * FROM @dir          

    if EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @dir WHERE [output] LIKE '%' + @filename + '%' )
    BEGIN
        --  File *was* found in this folder
        SET @bFileExists = 1  
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        --  File was NOT found in this folder
        SET @bFileExists = 0
    END

    SELECT @bFileExists
END
```

You can call this SP simply by passing it a folder name and a filename:

```
EXEC [dbo].[DoesFileExist] 'D:\MyFiles', 'SomeExcelFile.xls'
```

And yes, strangely, it does seem to work, for the SQL Server users who can't use `xp_fileexist`.

Remember that, to use this code, your SQL Server user must have permissions to use `xp_cmdshell` :

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO YourSQLServerUser
```

Comment: Additionally, if you are having problems, check permissions on your file. Right click on it, go to "Give Access" -> "Specific People" -> then select "Everyone"

Comment: If calling this SP with a low privilege user, this approach will require a proxy for cmdshell.